# Link folders in shared drive

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, shared-folders, hardlink, sharing

I'm a kinda new sysadmin and a user asked if it would be possible to optimise this process:

He works on department A and creates documentation in this structure:

> \server\department_a\projectx\documentation

every time he creates documentation there he has to manually copy and paste it to:

> \server\department_b\project_x\documentation

so the people from department B can get the documentation to send to the clients.

Is there any way to make it so every time he creates a file on `\\server\department_a\projectx\documentation` it is automatically copied to `\\server\department_b\project_x\documentation`?

I've tried making a softlink with mklink command, but it seems that it doesn't work on shared folders. Another option that comes to mind is to create a batch that automatically checks whether a new file is created on said folders and if so it copies it to the other one, but I would like to know if there's any other option that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third-party program such as [FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/)

> **Synchronize Files and Folders**
> Key featuresFreeFileSync is a folder comparison and synchronization software that creates and manages backup copies of all your important files. Instead of copying every file every time, FreeFileSync determines the differences between a source and a target folder and transfers only the minimum amount of data needed. FreeFileSync is Open Source software, available for Windows, macOS, and Linux.

I am not affiliated with it any way.